# change color button and set text Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i try and try but no success this my button

```
<div ng-class="User.active? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-success' "
     ng-click="User.active=!User.active">
    {{ User.active ? 'Desactive' : 'Active'}}
</div>
```

and my objective is to connect this button with this function 
desactivate and activate user

```
  public string Deactivate_User(AspNetUser User)
       {
        if (User == null) return "User Not Updated! Try Again";
        var userToUpdate = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 
  User.Id);
        if (userToUpdate == null) return "User Not Found.";
        if (userToUpdate.IsActive == true)
        {
            userToUpdate.IsActive = false;



        db.SaveChanges();
        return "User successfully deactivated.";
    }


        return "User already deactivated.";
    }
```

if the button is green then the function be like this

```
        public string Activate_User(AspNetUser User)
    {
        if (User == null) return "User Not Updated! Try Again";
        var userToUpdate = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 
        User.Id);
        if (userToUpdate == null) return "User Not Found.";
        if (userToUpdate.IsActive == false)
        {
            userToUpdate.IsActive = true;



            db.SaveChanges();
            return "User successfully activated.";
        }


        return "User already activated.";
    }
```

how i can open my problemm :
images :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt4r2.jpg)

[image]

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, one should avoid using DOM manipulation code such as `document.getElementById`. It violates the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of the [MVC framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). and makes unit testing difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it easier to use anchor tags rather than `input type="button"`.  You'll have more liberty to style and change things as you like and with the `ng-click` being what happens on a click they both fill the same role.

Presumably your user objects themselves have a property detailing whether or not they are active or deactive.

For your class, you can replace it with `ng-class="{btn: true; btn-danger: !User.active; btn-success: User.active}"`

This is equivalent to having your classes be `"btn btn-danger"` in the case that User.active is false and `"btn btn-success"` in the case that `User.active` is `true` and will change as the property on the user changes.  Since `btn-danger` is appearing red, I assume you have bootstrap css or similar so `btn-success` makes it look green.  If not, just modify your own css to match.

Next, inside of your `.then` for your http post, look at your response and check that it was a 200 and the back-end successfully activated your user at which point just set `User.active=true`.  You want to ensure that you actually *want* to update your user object by listening to the response.  Otherwise, by listening to the response and seeing that there was an error, you can use the `.then` in order to display an appropriate error message to the user.

As for changing the text on the button, you can use angular to do that as well.  Just let the text inside of the anchor be `{{User.active?'Deactivate':'Activate'}}`

```
<a ng-class="{btn: true; btn-danger: !User.active; btn-success: User.active}"
   ng-click="DesactivateUser(User)">\ 
 {{User.active?'Deactivate':'Activate'}}
</a>
```

Comment: thank you i put the button and work with succes but how to connected the function in my controller with angular with this button help me please

Comment: @aksil `ng-click="myFunctionName(arg)"` will run the function `myFunctionName` on the scope with argument `arg` on the scope.  Check that the function name for the ng-click matches the function name in the controller.  With what you have written above, you have `$scope.Delete = function(User)` but you have `ng-click="Desactivate(User)"`.  These don't match, so probably you want to rename the function to `$scope.Desactivate` instead or rename it something else more useful so that it can describe either activating *or* deactivating.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really do want differently named functions for activating vs deactivating, then you could have something like `ng-click="User.active?Activate(User):Desactivate(User)"`.  Deciding whether you are activating or deactivating can be controlled a lot more cleanly using the User object itself rather than trying to find the html element itself and parsing information from that.

Comment: thank you but i'am beginner in angular js and i try but no succes i edit my post you can find my button and my function can you make me a code to connect the function with the button you can if you doing changes in the button i need your help please i don't find the problem when itry controller you can find the images to understand me into my post