# User is not defined Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem when i click in the button it give me an error that user is not defined 
i don't know what the problem

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Active"
       ng-click="Active(User)" />
```

this is my function in page Controller Asp MVC :

```
public string Active(AspNetUser User)
    {
        if (User == null) return "User Not Updated! Try Again";
        var userToUpdate = db.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.Id == User.Id).FirstOrDefault();        
        if (userToUpdate == null) return "User Not Found.";
        if (userToUpdate.IsActive == true)
        {
            userToUpdate.IsActive = false;
    }
        else
        {
            if (userToUpdate.IsActive == false)
            {
                userToUpdate.IsActive = true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "User successfully Changed";
        }
        return "User already changed";
    }
```

and this is my Script :

```
$scope.Active = function() {  
    $http({
        method: "post",  
        url: "http://localhost:61484/AspNetUsers/Active",  
        datatype: "json",  
        data: JSON.stringify(User)  
    }).then(function(response) {  
        alert(response.data);  
        $scope.GetAllData();  
    })  
};
```

Comment: Please post the whole form to see how are you biding your model. Not possible to help with current example.

Comment: Hello, if your issue was resolved by my answer, consider marking as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing anything to the function `$scope.Active`. Pass the `User`:

```
$scope.Active = function(User) {...}
```

Comment: thank you its work but i want to change the button form like this   <div ng-class="User.IsActive? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-danger' " ng-click="User.IsActive=!User.IsActive">
                        {{ User.IsActive ? 'Active' : 'Desactive'}}
                    </div> **************************************************************************************how i can put ng click Activate with this button

Comment: can you correct me this button please to work with this function ******************************************************************************************************  <div ng-class="User.IsActive? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-danger' " ng-click="Active(User.IsActive=!User.IsActive)">
                        {{ User.IsActive ? 'Active' : 'Desactive'}}
                    </div>

Comment: @aksil This answers the question about "User is not defined Angular js". Questions about changing buttons on a form should be a separate question. Didn't someone already answer that for you in [change color button and set text Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606738/change-color-button-and-set-text-angular-js)???

Answer (score 0):

The `datatype` property is ignored by the AngularJS framework. Also it is not necessary to stringify JavaScript objects. The AngularJS framework does that automatically.

```
$scope.Active = function(user) {  
    $http({
        method: "post",  
        url: "http://localhost:61484/AspNetUsers/Active",  
        ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶t̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶"̶j̶s̶o̶n̶"̶,̶
        ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶J̶S̶O̶N̶.̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶i̶f̶y̶(̶U̶s̶e̶r̶)̶ 
        data: user  
    }).then(function(response) {  
        alert(response.data);  
        $scope.GetAllData();  
    })  
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)